# Django showing in a template a ManytoManyField that is into a Dictionary

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

The thing is quite simple but i don't know how to do it.
I got the next models.py

```
class ElementoDeRed(models.Model):

    IP_Address = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key= True)
    MAC_Address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    offset_bytes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transfered_bytes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    previous_bytes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    previous_previous_bytes = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dispositivos en mi nube'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dispositivos en mi nube'

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return smart_unicode(self.IP_Address)

class Register(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    network_element = models.ManyToManyField(ElementoDeRed)
    registered_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        #return smart_unicode(self.network_element)
        return smart_unicode("%s: %s" % (self.user,self.network_element.all()[0]))
```

As you can see, Register is using a `ElementoDeRed` element to storage on itself.

The thing is that i want to show in my template something like :

"The user <'user'> has the next device configured with this IP : <'IP_Address'>, Mac: <'Mac_Address'> ...."

What I am rendering on the template is a var called "dict_username_registers", is a dictionary witch key value is the username and the items asocciate to it are the "registers" fields. 
But im getting something like :

```
 david: [<Register: david: 10.0.0.3>, <Register: david: 10.0.0.1>] , Alice: <Register: Alice: 10.0.0.2>]
```

How can i access to that  field in HTML????
Thank you! Let me know if u need something else!

Comment: How is the dict defined? And why don't you access the relationship directly in the template, by iterating through `register.network_element.all`?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over the elements of `dict_username_registers` like this

```
{% for register in dict_username_registers %}
    accessing date {{register.registered_date}}
{% endfor %}
```

you car read more about those tags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-for)